# Dbvisualizer view table relationship

Tags: postgresql, dbvisualizer

I have a postgresql database with some tables. These tables have primary keys, but when I opened dbvisualizer, it didn't show me the relationships between tables.

[image]

How can I get the result with relationships?

Comment: Easiest is that you send a support request using Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer. Do also attach the script used to setup the tables and referential constraints with the support request.

Answer (score 0):

Check a few things:

1. Check off that "Show link name" option and try again
2. Open one single table and check its "Imported/Exported Keys" and see if it properly references other tables
3. Update your DbVisualizer - 10.0.22 version released this week with some issues fixed for the reference diagram
4. Get a Pro license and generate the DDL of the database to further inspect - comments in it may throw off the reference diagram function
5. [Submit a ticket](https://support.dbvis.com/support/tickets/new) to DbVis Software company - they probably need to get your database to help inspect